# Can the header of a table be pushed to the left but the column content be centered?

Tags: rows

I would like to have the first column centered. When I change to `l` instead of `Y` all the `\makecell{}`'s do not work anymore. How can I do this please?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{placeins}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{graphicx,booktabs,mhchem,makecell,array}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lYYYYYYYYY@{}}
    
    \toprule

    \textbf{\makecell{Region type\textbackslash \\IC per Car}} &  \textbf{IC1-0C} &  \textbf{IC1-1C} &  \textbf{IC1-2C} &  \textbf{IC2-0C} &  \textbf{IC2-1C} &  \textbf{IC2-2C} &  \textbf{IC3-0C} &  \textbf{IC3-1C} &  \textbf{IC3-2C} \\
     \cmidrule(lr){2-10} 
    \textbf{R1} &  84.525 &  14.038 &   1.437 &  53.287 &  35.188 &  11.526 &   9.720 &  28.090 &   0.622 \\
    \textbf{R2} &  85.181 &  14.068 &   0.751 &  55.938 &  38.756 &   5.306 &  20.618 &  49.456 &   0.299 \\
    \textbf{R3} &  75.060 &  23.887 &   1.052 &  51.086 &  42.191 &   6.722 &  20.291 &  53.723 &   0.260 \\
    \textbf{R4} &  78.795 &  18.953 &   2.252 &  52.918 &  42.833 &   4.249 &  15.119 &  59.352 &   0.255 \\
    \textbf{R5} &  75.646 &  21.645 &   2.709 &  43.881 &  48.455 &   7.664 &  17.071 &  49.619 &   0.333 \\
    \textbf{R6} &  79.597 &  19.128 &   1.275 &  46.832 &  44.734 &   8.435 &  20.732 &  50.852 &   0.284 \\
    \textbf{R7} &  79.597 &  19.128 &   1.275 &  46.832 &  44.734 &   8.435 &  20.732 &  50.852 &   0.284 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    %\end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:nn}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Change the `l` to a `c`?

Comment: Off-topic: You should also change `\makecell{...` to `\makecell[t]{...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd get away with boldface, that's unnecessary. In the first realization I use `\small` so the table fits.

However, you shouldn't overload cells: the second realization seems much clearer about what header refers to what columns.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\small

% local settings
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\newcommand{\HH}[2][c]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}#1@{}}#2\end{tabular}%
}
%%
    
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  c
  S[table-format=2.3]
  S[table-format=2.3]
  S[table-format=1.3]
  S[table-format=2.3]
  S[table-format=2.3]
  S[table-format=2.3]
  S[table-format=2.3]
  S[table-format=2.3]
  S[table-format=1.3]
  @{}
}
\toprule

\HH[l]{Region type\textbackslash \\ IC per Car} &
{\HH{IC1-\\0C}} &  {\HH{IC1-\\1C}} &  {\HH{IC1-\\2C}} &
{\HH{IC2-\\0C}} &  {\HH{IC2-\\1C}} &  {\HH{IC2-\\2C}} &
{\HH{IC3-\\0C}} &  {\HH{IC3-\\1C}} &  {\HH{IC3-\\2C}} \\
\midrule
R1 &  84.525 &  14.038 &   1.437 &  53.287 &  35.188 &  11.526 &   9.720 &  28.090 &   0.622 \\
R2 &  85.181 &  14.068 &   0.751 &  55.938 &  38.756 &   5.306 &  20.618 &  49.456 &   0.299 \\
R3 &  75.060 &  23.887 &   1.052 &  51.086 &  42.191 &   6.722 &  20.291 &  53.723 &   0.260 \\
R4 &  78.795 &  18.953 &   2.252 &  52.918 &  42.833 &   4.249 &  15.119 &  59.352 &   0.255 \\
R5 &  75.646 &  21.645 &   2.709 &  43.881 &  48.455 &   7.664 &  17.071 &  49.619 &   0.333 \\
R6 &  79.597 &  19.128 &   1.275 &  46.832 &  44.734 &   8.435 &  20.732 &  50.852 &   0.284 \\
R7 &  79.597 &  19.128 &   1.275 &  46.832 &  44.734 &   8.435 &  20.732 &  50.852 &   0.284 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:nn}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
%\small

% local settings
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\newcommand{\HH}[2][c]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}#1@{}}#2\end{tabular}%
}
%%
    
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  c
  S[table-format=2.3]
  S[table-format=2.3]
  S[table-format=1.3]
  S[table-format=2.3]
  S[table-format=2.3]
  S[table-format=2.3]
  S[table-format=2.3]
  S[table-format=2.3]
  S[table-format=1.3]
  @{}
}
\toprule

\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{c} Region \\ Type \end{tabular}} &
\multicolumn{9}{c}{IC per Car} \\
\cmidrule{2-10}
& {\HH{IC1-\\0C}} &  {\HH{IC1-\\1C}} &  {\HH{IC1-\\2C}}
& {\HH{IC2-\\0C}} &  {\HH{IC2-\\1C}} &  {\HH{IC2-\\2C}}
& {\HH{IC3-\\0C}} &  {\HH{IC3-\\1C}} &  {\HH{IC3-\\2C}} \\
\midrule
R1 &  84.525 &  14.038 &   1.437 &  53.287 &  35.188 &  11.526 &   9.720 &  28.090 &   0.622 \\
R2 &  85.181 &  14.068 &   0.751 &  55.938 &  38.756 &   5.306 &  20.618 &  49.456 &   0.299 \\
R3 &  75.060 &  23.887 &   1.052 &  51.086 &  42.191 &   6.722 &  20.291 &  53.723 &   0.260 \\
R4 &  78.795 &  18.953 &   2.252 &  52.918 &  42.833 &   4.249 &  15.119 &  59.352 &   0.255 \\
R5 &  75.646 &  21.645 &   2.709 &  43.881 &  48.455 &   7.664 &  17.071 &  49.619 &   0.333 \\
R6 &  79.597 &  19.128 &   1.275 &  46.832 &  44.734 &   8.435 &  20.732 &  50.852 &   0.284 \\
R7 &  79.597 &  19.128 &   1.275 &  46.832 &  44.734 &   8.435 &  20.732 &  50.852 &   0.284 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:nn-again}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, second option looks very good! Thanks for the tip too.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Is this what you are looking for? This uses `\makecell[t]{}` instead of `\makecell{}`, `\setlength\tabcolsep{4.5pt}` (the default is `6pt`), `\cmidrule(l){2-10}` instead of `\cmidrule(lr){2-10}` [*per @Mico*] and a `c` (as in centre) for the first column (instead of `Y` or `l`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{placeins}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{graphicx,booktabs,mhchem,makecell,array}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4.5pt}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:nn}
    
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}cYYYYYYYYY@{}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{\makecell[t]{Region type\textbackslash \\IC per Car}} &  \textbf{IC1-0C} &  \textbf{IC1-1C} &  \textbf{IC1-2C} &  \textbf{IC2-0C} &  \textbf{IC2-1C} &  \textbf{IC2-2C} &  \textbf{IC3-0C} &  \textbf{IC3-1C} &  \textbf{IC3-2C} \\
   \cmidrule(l){2-10}
    \textbf{R1} &  84.525 &  14.038 &   1.437 &  53.287 &  35.188 &  11.526 &   9.720 &  28.090 &   0.622 \\
    \textbf{R2} &  85.181 &  14.068 &   0.751 &  55.938 &  38.756 &   5.306 &  20.618 &  49.456 &   0.299 \\
    \textbf{R3} &  75.060 &  23.887 &   1.052 &  51.086 &  42.191 &   6.722 &  20.291 &  53.723 &   0.260 \\
    \textbf{R4} &  78.795 &  18.953 &   2.252 &  52.918 &  42.833 &   4.249 &  15.119 &  59.352 &   0.255 \\
    \textbf{R5} &  75.646 &  21.645 &   2.709 &  43.881 &  48.455 &   7.664 &  17.071 &  49.619 &   0.333 \\
    \textbf{R6} &  79.597 &  19.128 &   1.275 &  46.832 &  44.734 &   8.435 &  20.732 &  50.852 &   0.284 \\
    \textbf{R7} &  79.597 &  19.128 &   1.275 &  46.832 &  44.734 &   8.435 &  20.732 &  50.852 &   0.284 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

Additionally, I do not know which style guide you must adhere to but typically table captions go above tables and figure captions go below (although consult your guidelines). I changed the position but feel free to move it back.

Comment: Very simply explained! Thanks a lot!